# How can I deserialize a JSON field that is named "default" in the JSON? C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize to deserialize JSON from the youtubeapi. I created classes to implement the data structure of the JSON, which looks like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/9dlz1IIYCkI6XFpNy28ZfHloSKY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/xNIcXxr4UjrZ1ZnL0lGaAAqLc4k\"",
   "id": "r8Ni2m3ro30",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-09-25T17:49:08.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCeq7mOAcfee86UYyG8SCgvw",
    "title": "Long-Lasting Residual with Capreno Corn Herbicide",
    "description": "Watch growers talk about their experience with Capreno® corn herbicide's long-lasting residual. During unforgiving weather conditions, Capreno postemergence herbicide delivers season-long control of the toughest weeds to deliver an amazing end-of-season clean.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r8Ni2m3ro30/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r8Ni2m3ro30/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r8Ni2m3ro30/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The only problem is the thumbnails. I've made the following classes:

```
public class Thumbnails
{
    public Thumbnail default { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail medium { get;set; }
    public Thumbnail high { get;set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get;set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```

but in C# I can't name a parameter "default". I can't change the JSON though, and I need this default. It doesn't deserialize if I name it something different; "medium" and "high" deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Use an `@` to escape the keyword.

```
public Thumbnail @default { get; set; }
```